# WCF: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, soap

As this is very common problem but there is no proper solution which can fix this issue. I am also experiencing this "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly" problem for my WCF web services but its random and there is no specific scenario through which I can reproduce. I have been trying to fix this problem since couple of weeks and tried all possible solutions including increasing the timeout, enable/disable the keep-alive connection, open a new connection for each request and then close right after completion of the request but there is no luck. I have also enabled tracing and logging at both server and client side but couldn’t find such specific issue which may cause of this problem.

These WCF SOAP web services deployed on Windows server environment using the IIS 7 and .Net Framework 4.0

Client Side Tracing:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [351180] 00000000 :                                                 : 
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:44.4000839Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [351180] Exiting Socket#34051556::Receive()     -> Int32#0
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:44.4000839Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [351180] Socket#34051556::Dispose()
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:44.4000839Z
System.Net Error: 0 : [351180] Exception in HttpWebRequest#40245115:: - The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly..
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:44.4157088Z
System.Net Error: 0 : [351180] Exception in HttpWebRequest#40245115::GetResponse - The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly..
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:44.4157088Z
```

Server Side Tracing:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] Exiting DNS::GetHostByName()    -> IPHostEntry#31978062
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:16:20.7036270Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] Exiting DNS::GetHostAddresses()     -> IPAddress[]#52697188
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:16:20.7036270Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] DNS::GetHostAddresses()
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:03.3938764Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] DNS::GetHostByName()
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:03.3938764Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] Exiting DNS::GetHostByName()    -> IPHostEntry#39699746
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:03.4094763Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10808] Exiting DNS::GetHostAddresses()     -> IPAddress[]#12400315
    DateTime=2017-01-20T14:25:03.4094763Z
```

Tracing Config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
    <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
                    switchValue="Critical, Error, Warning, Verbose , Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
               <add name="sdt" 
                   type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
                   initializeData= "c:\stacktrace_log.log" />
            </listeners>
         </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I would appreciate if anyone can help to resolve this issue.

Comment: As the question is "very" clear only thing I can do is to guess. I think something crashing on server side. To get more details [enable tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) - this is common starting point for this error.

Comment: As I have already mentioned that I have enabled the tracing and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sorry I don't believe. Prove it.

Comment: I have included the client and server side tracing; please check and let me know if you need anything to figure this issue out.

Comment: Can you post the trace configuration? Looks like the required information haven't been logged. Have you tried to use [recommended configuration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I have included the tracing configuration settings.

Comment: Try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) configuration. It includes `ServiceModel.MessageLogging` which should give you more details what's going on in deeper level.I can't remember exactly which configuration provides details with exception message raised on server side. You should find the exception message somewhere in details while viewing the red item in SvcTraceViewer. Also you might get this error while sending large object, but you should find error details in trace and recommendation how to fix (one of the options is maxItemsInObjectGraph).

Comment: I have enabled the svc log as well and reviewed but unfortunately could't find any crashing at server side....as far as the message size is concerned there is no large messages and the interesting thing is that mostly it works for the same request and sometimes it is failed.

Comment: Another thing what could cause problem is undeclared `KnownType`. Maybe sometimes server tries to send unknown type and it ends with crash. But once again - you should see it in logs.

Comment: Try to also log the  `System.Runtime.Serialization` source. It will give you serialization exceptions if any.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have figured this issue out. The problem was with the load balancer's connection timeout which drops the connection when request takes longer than the limit defined in the load balancer. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Shahid, Can you please explain what you did to resolve this. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: As I explained earlier that in my case the problem with our load balancer which had connection timeout limit set 40 second and when call takes more than 40 seconds balancer was timedout and service was throwing this error without giving further details even there was nothing clear in the stack trace. This is very generic error which you can trace by putting some custom logging in your code.

Comment: @ShahidIqbal where should the logs be added? on client side or on server side where the wcf services are hosted?